# No default constructor exists for class. Initializer doesn't work either

Tags: c++

```
Game::Game(MainWindow& wnd)
    :
    wnd(wnd),
    gfx(wnd),
    brd(gfx),
    rng(std::random_device()()),
    snek({ 2,2 }),
    goal(rng,brd,snek)
    // Here it says that no default constructor for obstacle exists.
{
  std::uniform_int_distribution<int> xDist(brd.GetBoardX0(), brd.GetBoardX1() - 1);
  std::uniform_int_distribution<int> yDist(brd.GetBoardY0(), brd.GetBoardY1() - 1);

  for (int i = 0; i < obstacleCounter; ++i)
  {
      obstacle[i].Init(xDist(rng), yDist(rng), 130, 130, 130);
  }
}
```

It says that no default constructor for `obstacle` exists, however I created an initializer with the loop. That obstacle object is a 100-array. I thought making an initializer that way would work.

EDIT: It is solved now. It seems the former constructor I had created long ago was not well written. Many thanks to everyone!

Comment: What is `obstacle`? What constructors does it have?

Comment: Have you tried making a default constructor for `Obstacle`? That's what the error message is trying to tell you. In C++ any array type needs a default constructor.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen, `obstacle` is an object I created from `Obstacle` class. The constructors are the same as `goal(rng,brd,snek)`. However, it it asking me for a default one.

Comment: @john Yes, I tryed, and the it says "only () is allowed as initializer for for array member "Game::obstacle".

Comment: Well, you need to initalize it then. All of the `Obstacle` instances in array must be initialized. You can also add default constructor then (if your `Init()` method will initialize the object properly) or use `std::vector<Obstacle> obstacle` and initialize it in member initializer list `obstacle {number_of_items, Obstacle{rng,brd,snek}}